# I have a pair of bricks that I would like identified. They are like a Slope 33 3 x 3 Double Convex Corner but with an uptick

Tags: part-identification

I have a pair of unusual bricks that I would like identified, I have lost the instructions so cannot identify them.

I have tried searching on Bricklink and Rebrickable (even Google Image search) but cannot find them.

They are like a Dark Red [3675](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3675#T=C) (Slope 33 3 x 3 Double Convex Corner) but with an uptick on the opposite corner.

[image: photo]

EDIT:

It's certainly not warped, it is curved by design, but perhaps it is not genuine lego, although I cannot remember buying any other sets.

[image: photo2]

Comment: Are there any letter or number markings anywhere on the part? Inside the stud hole, underneath?

Comment: I suspect this is not a LEGO element. I would expect to see "LEGO" inside studs.

Comment: Just has the number 6 underneath, LEGO does not appear when the holes are inverted like that.

Comment: What = an uptick? Can't see it. Maybe Minitalia, Italian Lego 1970's as hollow stud.

Comment: @james.cookie since when does LEGO not have their logo inside recessed studs? Maybe you aren't looking at LEGO elements in your collection? I did a quick check on few random parts than have recessed stud (a window frame, Technic brick and a brick with studs sideways) and all of them have a LEGO logo inside. Same window frame has a logo inside all recessed studs, even the one that have PIP (Plastic Injection Point) like you see in your picture and still have a logo there, albeit less readable/incomplete. And your piece is large enough to have more than "6" as Part ID on the underside.

Comment: Alex - perhaps you are right, I have checked other parts with recessed studs and they do all have the logo inside (just never noticed before!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it - it's Kre-O rubbish:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hasbro-Transformers-Grimlock-Street-Attack/dp/B00KONR5Z6

[image: photo]